# RxSwift - UIImageView - observe property isHighlighted

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to observe the property "isHighlighted" on the object UIImageView, but seems like my code is not correct? Any idea?

```
imageView.rx
.observe(Optional<Bool>.self, "isHighlighted")
.subscribe {

}
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

When I set the imageView highlighted, nothing subscribes.

Comment: The correct answer is, don't do that. You should not be observing your view to implement logic. You should have a model in your code that knows if the view *should be* highlighted and whatever you were going to put in the subscribe would be attached to the *model*. Your imageView's isHighlighted should also be attached to that model.

Comment: @DanielT. it's not always the case, imagine you handle touch input, and its output is computed/based on the view state (not state coming from viewmodel, but it's size, like width, height etc.) then passing touch input coordinates outside of view doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Add this extension to your project:

```
public extension Reactive where Base: UIImageView {
    var isHighlighted: ControlEvent<Void> {
        let source = self.methodInvoked(#selector(setter: Base.isHighlighted)).map { _ in }
        return ControlEvent(events: source)
    }
}
```

Now you can use observe the changes to the `isHighlighted` property:

```
imageView.rx.isHighlighted.bind {
    if imageView.isHighlighted {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try using `Bool.self` as `isHighlighted` is not a optional property

```
imageView.rx
            .observe(Bool.self, "isHighlighted")
            .subscribe(onNext: { (isHighlighted) in

            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Tried, the same. Passing just once when initialized, not observing the changes.

Comment: are you setting the `imageView.highlightedImage = UIImage(named: "someImage")` and `imageView.isHighlighted = true`

Comment: yes, I have a logic switching the highlighted state with different images. So images are changing, but not working observation of isHighlighted

Answer (score -1):

You can create an extension:

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIImageView {

    /// Bindable sink for `isHighlighted` property.
    public var isHighlighted: Binder<Bool> {
        return Binder(base) { imageView, isHighlighted in
            imageView.isHighlighted = isHighlighted
        }
    }

}
```

and then subscribe to it (or bind it):

```
self.imageview.rx
    .isHighlighted
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] isHighlighted in
        ...
})
```

Comment: results in "Value of type 'Binder<Bool>' has no member 'subscribe'", correct?

Comment: Correct, this answer allows you to *update* isHighlighted through an observable. It doesn't allow you to get notified of changes.